# Python library remotior_sensus installation

Tags: qgis

How to install the python library remotior_sensus, so that I can continue using SCP. I have been using QGIS. I have also been working with very high resolution images for landcover mapping, but I didn't had any luck.

Comment: Could you please me more specific in what you have done so far so users can guide you better?

Comment: I am trying to install python remotior_sensus with my qgis, i was able to install but the semi-autoclassification tool doesn't work.

Comment: Which QGIS version?

Comment: I am having the same issue while installing SCP plugin. I am using QGIS 3.32.3 Lima. I get the following alert: > semi-automatic classification plugin: error, Please, Install the required Python library remotior_sensus

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue. I am running QGIS LTR 3.28.11 on a Mac. I had the SCP plugin installed for some time. The last time I updated the SCP plugin (8.0.8?), I got this same message: 
'Please install the required Python library remotior_sensus'. 
Then a new update showed up (8.0.9), and I installed it, but the error remains.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it by using the older version [7.10.11](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/version/7.10.11/) of the SCP Plugin.

Just download the .zip and use the *Install from ZIP* option.

Answer (score -2):

You can follow this link as a guide:
https://fromgistors.blogspot.com/p/remotior-sensus.html

The process involves downloading the remote sensing and GIS python package called Remotior Sensus. The other dependencies are   gdml,NumPy, SciPy, GDAL; optionally scikit-learn and PyTorch https://fromgistors.blogspot.com/2023/02/remotior-sensus-basic-tutorial.html or just follow this instructions https://semiautomaticclassificationmanual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation_win64.html#qgis-download-and-installation

Answer (score -3):

Type this text in CMD and then restart QGIS (this is the link I used - Type this text in CMD and then restart QGIS (This is the link I used)
pip3 install --upgrade remotior-sensus scikit-learn torch)

pip3 install --upgrade remotior-sensus scikit-learn torch

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This won't work with 90% of QGIS installations which do *not* use the system-wide Python. What does the "This is the link I used" text means?

Comment: This did not work in my QGIS LTR 3.28.11 on a Mac.